# How to set specific ThemeResource for Image control through binding with MVVM?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have an app in which I have defined multiple ThemeResources to set the correct Source for multiple images that I would like to use. I have about a dozen Images for which I can let the app automatically set the Light or Dark theme as required.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <Style x:Key="ShowImage" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/image-light.png"/>                            
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <Style x:Key="ShowImage" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" value="Assets/image-dark.png"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>                
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Now if I want set a specific Image inline in XAML I use the following code.

```
<Grid>        
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
       Stretch="None" 
       Style="{ThemeResource ShowImage}">
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

This works perfectly for all my images and follows the correct theme always.

I'am now trying to change this code. The image that i must show is based on some logic and calculations which i perform in an MVVM ViewModel.

In my ViewModel I have a property of type string 'ImageToShow' that contains the name of the ThemeResource for the Image that must be shown.

I would like to use the property in the ViewModel to perform the ThemeResource assignment to the Image control. so for example the following .. in this case the property ImageToshow would contain the string value `ShowImage`.

```
<Grid>        
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
       Stretch="None" 
       Style="{ThemeResource ImageToShow}">
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

This however gives me a XamlParseException.

Is it possible to set the ThemeResource through binding from MVVM? Or should I use some sort of converter to make sure that the value of the string is used to select the ThemeResource.

Comment: `<Image Source="{Binding ImageToShow}"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should be able to access the relevant resource for the currently selected Theme using the `Application.Current.Resources` object... eg.:

```
Image image = (Image)Application.Current.Resources["ShowImage"];
```

Therefore, you should be able to return that value from the setter of your view model property like this:

```
public Image ImageToShow
{
    get { return (Image)Application.Current.Resources["ShowImage"]; }
}
```

The only problem with this is that you will need to manually notify the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface when the property value has changed so that the UI will be notified of the change:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageToShow");
```

You can find an example of how to do that in the [User Interface : Detecting Changes in the Theme Template](http://mscerts.wmlcloud.com/windows_phone/user%20interface%20%20%20detecting%20changes%20in%20the%20theme%20template.aspx) page on the MSCerts website.

Please refer to the [How to apply theme resources for Windows Phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn518235.aspx) page on MSDN for further information.

Comment: Hi Sheridan, Sorry for the late response. I will try to work it out with you solution and let you know the results. Robin.

Comment: Hi Sheridan, thanks. Your answer put me on the right course. But it indeed breaks the automatic switching of the Images to Dark or Light Theme at runtime. When the App starts the next time it is correctly applied again. So I will further investigate setting the correct Theme at runtime with the link you send. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @RobinSmits - Did you come to any solution? I find I'm in the same boat. I can get an image programatically but this breaks at runtime when the theme switches. 

Also Application.Current.Resources["ShowImage"] only returns the dark theme image, even if your in the light theme.